# THX-1138 Redub, would be great to get some feedback.

Tags: sound-design, scifi

Hi there, I'm a film student interested in sound design on a practical and theoretical level. For a recent assignment I recreated the sound in a scene from one of my favourite films, THX-1138. I went for a more minimalist approach than the original, focusing on creating eerie room tones and atmospheres as well as using various aircraft sounds to create the car noises.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated :)

http://vimeo.com/36538708

Answer (score 1):

Hi Jamie!

I checked out your video and a couple things stood out to me:

I liked the room tones, and the slow builds.  The computer sounds and typing were appropriate.  You supported the change in on-screen energy between the computer room and the traffic/tunnels.  Also, when he's driving in traffic and we hear the whooshes, engine sound etc - that worked very well for me.

As for the "bad stuff", In some of your clips I heard clicking at the beginning and end of the clips.  You'll want to fade in/out or xfade for a fraction of a second to get rid of that.  Also, and this is a design issue and I have more experience as an editor and mixer, but I think you may want to consider altering some of the aircraft sounds a little by pitching them or mixing in other similar sounds so they don't sound so much like aircraft.

I'm hesitant to go into detail about anything regarding design theory because of my lack of knowledge so I guess that's all I have to offer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree that some of the clips are a bit messy, will definitely go back and tidy them up. 
Cheers :) 

Answer (score 1):

Hey nice work first off, especially for a first stab at this.

I would say attempt to layer and manipulate the sounds you're using. It sounds like aircrafts. Add extra elements, It sounds monstrous in the original like theres a ton of afterburners going off, experiment, use things you don't expect, distort, stretch, etc etc.

The bike sounds were nice, but did you create them or were they just something you found? Good work though.